# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)" with the below code. Please help me!!
I am trying to lemmatize and cut off common words and then add to library so I can identify most common words and find the relationship between words.

```
def build_dataset(words, vocabulary_size):
    lexicon = []
    for l in words: 
        all_words = word_tokenize(l.lower())
        lexicon += list(all_words )
    lexicon = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in lexicon] 
    w_counts = Counter(lexicon) 
    word = [] 
    for w in w_counts:
        if 5000 > w_counts[w] > 50 :
            word.append(w) 
    print(len(word))
    return word

    count = [['UNK', -1]]
    count.extend(collections.Counter(word).most_common(vocabulary_size - 1))
    dictionary = dict()
    for l2, _ in count:
        dictionary[l2] = len(dictionary)
        data = list()
        unk_count = 0
    for l2 in word:
        if l2 in dictionary:
            index = dictionary[l2]
        else:
            index = 0 
            unk_count += 1
            data.append(index)
            count[0][1] = unk_count
            reverse_dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys())) 
        return data, count, dictionary, reverse_dictionary     
data, count, dictionary, reverse_dictionary = build_dataset(words, vocabulary_size)
```

Comment: Is the indentation right? You seem to have an unconditional `return word` in the middle of the function. More than four items in the array would be too many for the tuple you're unpacking the return value of the function, right?

Comment: Easiest way to debug a "too many values to unpack" error is to just take the return value as 1 variable, then print that 1 variable. It will end up being a tuple of some number of variables that doesn't equal 4. It'll be clear what you're getting back from your function at that point and you can correct for it.

Comment: @ikkachu Thank you!! solved the prob!!